# Entity Framework - How to query object based on bridge table values?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

First, about my table setup:

```
Group:
    groupId - int
    groupName - varchar

Schedule:
    scheduleId - int
    scheduleName - varchar

Group_Schedules
    scheduleId - int/fk to Schedule
    groupId - int/fk to Group
```

I'm using the EF, in the above scenario, no EF entity is created to represent Group_Schedules, instead a collection is added to Group and Schedule tables representing the other end.

I need to get all groups that belong to a schedule and have my return be an `IQueryable<Group>`. I.e (and no, this doesn't work because of the way EF generates the bridge table):

```
var g = from g in context.Groups
        where g.Group_Schedule.scheduleId = 1 // This doesn't work because Group_Schedule is a collection of Schedule
        select g;
```

Is there an elegant way to get the data I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these will return an `IQueryable<Group>`:

```
var groups = from g in db.Groups
             where g.Schedules.Any(s => s.scheduleId == 1)
             select g;

var groups = (from s in db.Schedules
              where s.scheduleId == 1
              select s.Groups).SelectMany(g => g);
```